# Failed opening and inclusion

Tags: php

I really hope that someone can help me, because I have tried everything now in 4 days, and I am just stuck. I had a question with this before that did not get solved.

When I click one of my buttons "register" I get the following error:

```
Warning: include(resources/includes/header.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/php/global/registernumbers.php on line 5

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'resources/includes/header.html' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/php/global/registernumbers.php on line 5
```

Here is the relevant code:

**header.html:**

```
<!-- 1 button in the header -->
    <li>
       <a href="php/global/registernumbers.php">Register 1</a> <!-- Error -->
    </li>

    <!-- registernumbers.php is called fine. I can see my <h1> and <h2> text -->
```

**registernumbers.php:**

```
<?php
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
?>

<?php include 'resources/includes/header.html'; ?>

<h1>Register Numbers</h1>
<h2>global/registernumbers</h2>
```

My folder structure is looking like this:

[image: Folder structure]

```
  ../../php/resources/includes/header.html
        Is working, but the CSS is ofcourse not called.

        resources/includes/header.html
        This is the correct path, but here I get the error

        <?php include(ROOT_PATH . 'resources/includes/header.html'); ?>
        Does not work either
```

The path to the header is correct, and I even tried to uinstall MAMP. 
When I use this:

When I put the  `header.html` and `registernumbers.php`, where my `index.php` is, everything is working fine.

Does anybody have a clue on what I can do? I would really like to seperate my files in folders like this.

**Updated code after response**

```
<?php
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
?>

<?php define 'APP_ROOT', '/resources/includes/header.html'; ?>

<h1>Register Numbers</h1>
<h2>global/registernumbers</h2>

<?php define ('APP_ROOT', '/resources/includes/header.html'); ?>
// Here I do not get any errors, but the header is not called either

<?php define 'APP_ROOT', '/resources/includes/header.html'; ?>
//Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''APP_ROOT'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/php/global/registernumbers.php on line 5
```

Comment: I'd suggest you set an application wide constant for APP_ROOT, or similar (equal to the path to your website folder. Then you can do `APP_ROOT . '/resources/includes/header.html`. The problem you're having atm is when you try including a file in registernumbers.php it will start looking _from that folder_, not the project root. ie: `something/website/php/global/resources/includes/header.html`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I tried to add your suggestion instead of my include. Then I get this error: Notice: Use of undefined constant APP_ROOT - assumed 'APP_ROOT' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website/php/global/registernumbers.php on line 5

Comment: Where/how did you set the constant?

Comment: you need to define the `APP_ROOT` like this, `define("APP_ROOT", "/some/dir")`

Comment: @McDuck4, what Saitama means is to `define("APP_ROOT", "/some/dir");` and then use that defined variable like `include(APP_ROOT."/relative/path/to.file");`.

Comment: Is it something like this?: `<?php define("APP_ROOT", "Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website"); ?>
<?php include(APP_ROOT. "/resources/includes/header.html"); ?>`

Comment: /some/dir should that be /htdocs/website or the whole path?

Comment: Shoot :-( No solution again. I thank you for your suggestions.